# How to persist Rancher server meta data

Tags: docker, rancher

I had setup Rancher on my laptop using Vagrant. For some reason I had to reboot the laptop leading to start Vagrant VM using vagrant up.

After Vagrant vm came up, I have rancher server container running but it has lost all meta data. I have lost all hosts and that were added to it as well as lost all users that wee added to rancher server.

Please let share how we can persist rancher server meta data.

Thanks

Comment: I found that rancher server container has mysql installed. Probably it stores meta info in mysql. If we can provide a way to change default mysql data dir to some persisted location that would do the job.

Comment: Information about how to externalize meta db is available on https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/302

Comment: http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/upgrading/

Comment: http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/installing-rancher/installing-server/

Answer (score 1):

I think you pretty much answered your own question. But there are options:

- Bind mount the MySQL `/var/lib/mysql` data folder to the host so removing / starting new containers don't lose the data. This is documented at http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/installing-rancher/installing-server/#bind-mount-mysql-volume.
- Start a MySQL container (that in turn should use a volume of some kind for data) and connect to it with a link or manual TCP connection settings. This is documented at http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/installing-rancher/installing-server/#using-an-external-database.
- Start the existing `rancher-server` container that was stopped. The data shouldn't just disappear from inside the container (unless you deleted the container after it stopped). Though, it is easier to make sure of this using one of the above two options.